# Assigning every 3rd word from a txt file to a variable

Tags: python

I'm supposed to use a txt file and select every 3rd word and assign it to the variable "three". This is what i have so far I don't know where to go from here.

```
fname = "school_prompt.txt"
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        three = f.read().split()
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've understood your assignment correctly? This makes very little sense as you keep overwriting the value without doing anything with it...

Comment: Not really no, and I noticed how I should've probably put the read and split part outside the for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for line in f:` already puts the line as a string in `line`. You shouldn't do `f.read()` afterwards.

You want the whole text first so do this:

```
fname = "school_prompt.txt"
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
```

Now `text` is the content of the whole file. 
You can split it: `words = text.split()`

Now it should be easy to get every third word in a list:

```
three = words[0::3]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, I get an error that says 'list' object has no attribute 'split' on line 4, and line 4 says words = text.split() and after that I put three = words[0::3]

Comment: Oops. Wait fixing

Comment: Fixed. The seconds split was redundant

Comment: no issue now but I don't get the same result, it should start on the third word so I changed the first value in [0::3] to [2::3] but now it doesn't increment by 3's

Comment: How about `words[0::3][1:]`?

Comment: still nothing :/

Comment: Nothing as in? Could you post the file and your expected output?

Comment: I just realized its 3rd word from every line put into a list

Comment: Then you can do this: `three = [l.split()[2] for l in f]`